# Pandas: Transpose the first 3 rows but duplicate the rest of the data so I get a unique row and a larger table

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to convert an existing excel sheet that has 3 layers of columns.  The first column is the year, but it's a merged cell. The 2nd column is of the months, also merged, and the 3rd layer is alternating Rent | Other.

Original data is shaped like this:

My data looks like this:

| 2022 | Unnamed: 1 | Unnamed: 2 | Unnamed: 3 ... | 2023 | Unnamed: 135 | Unnamed: 136 ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| January | NaN | February | NaN | January | NaN | February |
| Rent | Other | Rent | Other | Rent | Other | Rent |
| 100 | 0 | 120 | 30 | 110 | 25 | 100 |

- I added the "...." to the table, this continues for ~130 or so columns per year.

I tried to forward fill the year and months:

| 2022 | 2022 | 2022 | 2022 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| January | January | February | February |
| Rent | Other | Rent | Other |
| 100 | 0 | 120 | 30 |

I want it to look like this:

| Year | Month | Rent | Other |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | January | 100 | 0 |
| 2022 | February | 120 | 30 |

Comment: can you give the data to build the dataframe with `df.iloc[:6,:4].to_dict()`, as your question is about dataframe shape, starting from the wrong one will not help you much

Comment: How are you creating the DataFrame in the first place? You should avoid having this extra rows of header as date in the first place

Comment: @Ben.T  I updated the post. I appreciate the help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flying blind here since I don't have access to your Excel file.

```py
df = (
    # Your file look to be row-oriented instead of pandas' usual column-oriented
    # format. We will import it without column names and assign them later.
    pd.read_excel("file.xlsx", header=None)
    # Fill in the blanks since some of the cells are merged
    .ffill(axis=1)
    # Set the row's index, then transpose the dataframe to the usual
    # column-oriented format
    .set_axis(["Year", "Month", "Metric", "Value"])
    .T
)

# Month name is usually a pain in the neck to work with. By default, they sort
# in alphabetical order so April, August, February, ... It's best to convert
# them into number, but if you want to keep the name, use CategoricalDType to
# keep them in semantic order
MonthDType = pd.CategoricalDtype(
    pd.date_range("2022-01-01", "2022-12-01", freq="M").strftime("%B"), ordered=True
)
df["Month"] = df["Month"].astype(MonthDType)

# The final pivot
df = df.pivot_table(
    index=["Year", "Month"],
    columns="Metric",
    values="Value",
    aggfunc="sum",
    observed=True,
).reset_index()
```